# How to execute a unique random function

Tags: python

I want to make a script that types out unique random words, this is my code so far:

```
import pynput
import random
import time
from pynput import keyboard
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller

def hi():
   keyboard = Controller()
   keyboard.type('hi')
   keyboard.press(Key.enter)
   time.sleep(random.randint(1, 2))

def hello():
   keyboard = Controller()
   keyboard.type('hello')
   keyboard.press(Key.enter)
   time.sleep(random.randint(1, 2))

def world():
   keyboard = Controller()
   keyboard.type('world')
   keyboard.press(Key.enter)
   time.sleep(random.randint(1, 2))
```

What should I do to execute a **unique** function every time?

*The desired output example*:

```
hello
world
hi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `random.choice()`. and `for` loop to repeat the function

so add this to your code:

```
functions = [hi, hello, world]
donefunc = []
def unique_word(func_list):
    global donefunc
    function = random.choice(func_list)
    while function in donefunc:
        function = random.choice(func_list)
    function()
    donefunc.append(function)
for i in range(len(functions)):
    unique_word(functions)
```

The whole code:

```
import pynput
import random
import time
from pynput import keyboard
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller

def hi():
   keyboard = Controller()
   keyboard.type('hi')
   keyboard.press(Key.enter)
   time.sleep(random.randint(1, 2))

def hello():
   keyboard = Controller()
   keyboard.type('hello')
   keyboard.press(Key.enter)
   time.sleep(random.randint(1, 2))

def world():
   keyboard = Controller()
   keyboard.type('world')
   keyboard.press(Key.enter)
   time.sleep(random.randint(1, 2))

functions = [hi, hello, world]
donefunc = []
def unique_word(func_list):
    global donefunc
    function = random.choice(func_list)
    while function in donefunc:
        function = random.choice(func_list)
    function()
    donefunc.append(function)

for i in range(len(functions)):
    unique_word(functions)
```

From the Tomerikoo's comment (set):

```
import pynput
import random
import time
from pynput import keyboard
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller

def hi():
   keyboard = Controller()
   keyboard.type('hi')
   keyboard.press(Key.enter)
   time.sleep(random.randint(1, 2))

def hello():
   keyboard = Controller()
   keyboard.type('hello')
   keyboard.press(Key.enter)
   time.sleep(random.randint(1, 2))

def world():
   keyboard = Controller()
   keyboard.type('world')
   keyboard.press(Key.enter)
   time.sleep(random.randint(1, 2))

functions = [hi, hello, world]
donefunc = set()
def unique_word(func_list):
    global donefunc
    function = random.choice(func_list)
    while function in donefunc:
        function = random.choice(func_list)
    function()
    donefunc.add(function) 

for i in range(len(functions)):
    unique_word(functions)
```

Comment: This is the best one so far, but I don't want it to repeat the same function twice

Comment: @Rayr Oh, okay fixed.

Comment: Thank you so much it worked perfectly, but can you explain the last part in your code? (in the "whole code" part)

Comment: @Rayr What last part, `append` part or `for`-loop? or some other part?

Comment: @Rayr oh, what's confusing about that?

Comment: @ppwater one more question, how can I loop this? (sorry I'm kinda new to python)

Comment: Loop what? (maybe wrap it around in for-loop?)

Comment: `donefunc` can be a `set` as we're talking about unique stuff (for slightly more efficiency)

Comment: This is slightly overkill for what we want to do. We can just use `random.shuffle` and iterate over the shuffled function list like in my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a function for that. Here's how:

But first make a list containing all the function names.

```
functions = [hi, hello, world]

def unique_word(func_list):
    function = random.choice(func_list)
    function()

unique_word(functions)
```

This function calls random functions everytime you call it.

But if you want to produce a random order for the three function output use this instead.

```
functions = [hi, hello, world]

random.shuffle(functions)

for function in functions:
    function()
```

Comment: `random.choice(func_list)()`

Comment: Yeah you can do that too. But I like using variables just in case I want to add some more functionality.

Comment: @ppwater Yeah this is only one execution, if you want the expected output you should enclose the function call inside of a `for` loop.

Comment: @Tomerikoo The **unique** part is that every function which is chosen at random is **unique** and is not a duplicate funtion.

Comment: @Tomerikoo I am editing the code for two different results. One choosing from a list of unique functions and the other for producing unique text. Check the edited code.

Comment: @Tomerikoo Yeah sorry I forgot that `random.shuffle` doesn't return a new list. Now I fixed it though.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to put your functions in a list and then [`shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) them:

```py
import random

funcs = [hi, hello, world]
random.shuffle(funcs)

for func in funcs:
    func()
```

If you don't want to shuffle in-place, you can use [`sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) to create a new list of functions:

```py
funcs = [hi, hello, world]

for func in random.sample(funcs, k=len(funcs)):
    func()
```